# Ubuntu MAAS DNS not forwarding request

Tags: networking, dns, maas

I am trying out MAAS but I am having trouble getting the node to reach the internet.  This is my setup:

3 physical machine, with 1 of them having two network cards acting as gateway, cluster controllers and region controller.  The gateway/controller is setup to have one interface receive IP from the corporate network and while having the other managed by MAAS (both DHCP and DNS.)

From the gateway, I have no problem reaching out, but the Nodes cannot.  I looked at the controller/gateway, I can see that bind9 is running.

```
$ service bind9 status
 * bind9 is running
```

Doing `dig ubuntu.com` give me results.  But if I do `dig @127.0.0.1 ubuntu.com`, I get no return.  I also look through the bind config and everything seems to be in order (forwarder is setup.)  What am I missing?

Here are the relevant bind configs

```
$ cat /etc/bind/named.conf
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

$ cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options
options { directory "/var/cache/bind";
dnssec-validation auto;
include "/etc/bind/maas/named.conf.options.inside.maas";
auth-nxdomain no;
listen-on-v6 { any; }; };

$ cat /etc/bind/maas/named.conf.options.inside.maas 
    forwarders {
        172.24.3.136;
    };
```

Comment: Further investigation I found this error from /var/log/syslog

Oct 15 18:00:14 OpenStackProtoRegionMaster named[25021]: validating @0x7ffe08181cc0: . NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the "got insecure response" is the issue.  Found this solution from StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14923549/1692452

> This is related to the new DNSSEC feature which is now enabled by default. This might indicate the DNS resolvers/forwarders you are using does not support DNSSEC so the response appear to be insecure to your server.
>
> You can either use resolvers that support DNSSEC or temporarily disable the feature on your server. To disable it, simply use those parameters in your “named.conf” :
>
> `dnssec-enable no; dnssec-validation no;`

Answer (score 0):

Beside dnssec issues reported in the OP's answer (`no valid RRSIG resolving ...`), I also had issues with IPv6, which manifested themselves like so:

```
maas1 named[1532]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:503:c27::2:30#53
```

The solution was to start `bind9` in v4 mode only.  To achieve this, I leveraged [this article](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/145568) (I'm using MAAS 2.1 on Xenial, which is running systemd):

1. `sudo systemctl cat bind9.service | grep ExecStart`.  This provides the current cmdline used to start the `bind9` daemon.
2. `sudo systemctl edit bind9.service`.  An empty editor appears which allows overriding the required aspects of the service definition.
3. Add the `-4` flag to the `ExecStart` cmdline noted previously at save the file.  In my case it looks like this:

   ```
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -4 -f -u bind
   ```

   (NB: the first blank `ExecStart=` is intended - refer to the  [aforementioned article](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/145568)).
4. If you'd like to check that your override is in place, you can re-run: `systemctl cat bind9.service`
5. `systemctl restart bind9.service`
6. Run a few requests from nodes and check all is good with: `systemctl status bind9.service` - previously this was chock full of the errors mentioned above.