# How to set forwarders on MAAS Bind9 + openstack-install

Tags: networking, dns, maas, openstack, landscape

I'm installing Openstack using openstack-install (MAAS+juju+landscape), and I got stuck on the first bootstrap forever.
After some troubleshooting I realize the problem was DNS.
On the bootstrap machine, the DNS is MAAS IP, which is good, but that DNS didn't have internet name resolution. What to do? forwarders, right?
I found [Ubuntu MAAS DNS not forwarding request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537540/ubuntu-maas-dns-not-forwarding-request) and did something like that and worked... for a while.

Basically what I did, was to modify from "auto" to "no" in this line in **/etc/bind/named.conf.options**:

> dnssec-validation no;

And I added this line:

> forwarders { 192.168.10.7 ; };

Restart bind9 and name resolution worked fine. 
The problem is after "something" (probably something I touched on MAAS), the forwarder line disappeared.

This is what happened on the bootstrap without forwarder on the MAAS DNS:

```
ubuntu@marin:~$ ping www.emol.com
ping: unknown host www.emol.com
```

And this when I added the forwarder:

```
ubuntu@marin:~$ ping www.emol.com
PING ip11.yah.cl (200.12.20.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 200.12.20.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=245 time=8.01 ms
64 bytes from 200.12.20.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=245 time=7.62 ms
```

Now the questions:

1. Why on the Boostrap's DNS appears only the MAAS server's IP if I configure multiple DNS in MAAS -- Networks -- Edit internal network -- DNS Servers (I used spaces between DNS Servers)
2. How can I configure forwarders on MAAS DNS (maybe on the GUI or thru MAAS CLI commands)?

PS: I'm using MAAS version 1.7.2+bzr3355-0ubuntu1~trusty1

Answer (score 2):

1) Could be a possible bug, the MAAS UI should support multiple entries.

2) You'll need to make your changes within /etc/bind/maas/named.conf* as those files are included into the top level named options.